# tex4ht place maintext and footnote in the same file

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, htxelatex

I'm using `tex4ht`, or more specifically `htxelatex`, to convert a rather large xelatex file to HTML but I noticed that all my footnotes are turned into separate HTML files. Is there a way to tell the program that I want to place the footnotes in the same file as the main text?

To illustrate the problem, I have the following MWE (which I named httest.tex):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    test\footnote{footnotetext}
\end{document}
```

This produces two files: `httest.html` containing

> text<sup>1</sup>

and `httest2.html` containing

> <sup>1</sup>footnotetext

I want it to produce a single file named `httest.html` that contains

> text<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup>footnotetext

Comment: Regarding the superscript: the StackExchange sites support a limited subset of html tags, among which `<sup></sup>` and `<sub></sub>` for superscript and subscript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, you can achieve what you want using the `fn-in` option:

```
make4ht -x httest "fn-in"
```

I would use [make4ht](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html#x1-40003) instead of `htxelatex`, as it has much more features and fixes some issues.

This is the rendered HTML:

[image]